# sql case statement with group by clause

Tags: sql-server

[image]

```
SELECT 
    MAX(srNo)         AS srNo,
    MAX(eventDesc)    AS eventDesc,
    attributeType     AS attributeType,
    MAX(companyCode)  AS companyCode,
    empCode           AS empCode,
    SUM(CAST(oldValue AS DECIMAL(10, 1))) AS oldValue,
    CASE 
       WHEN isnumeric(newValue) = 1 THEN SUM(CAST(newValue AS DECIMAL(10, 1)))
       ELSE max(newValue)
    END               AS newValue,       
    MAX(creationDate),
    createdByEmp,
    reason 
FROM   
    dummy 
GROUP BY
    creationDate, reason, createdByEmp, attributeType, empCode
```

I want to add in newValue if it contains number else display as it is.

This query returns the following output

[image]

Help me please! Thank you.

Comment: What will happen if the same group have both `isnumeric(newValue) = 1` and `isnumeric(newValue) = 0` ? You can't both sum and max the same column

Comment: The error is crystal clear - the `dummy.newValue` is neither being aggregated (by e.g. a `MAX`, `SUM`, `COUNT` function), nor is it in the `GROUP BY` list of columns - you cannot have that. You need to **either** aggregate your `newValue`, or add it to the `GROUP BY` list of columns.

Comment: then what is soluntion for this i have to add if it contains number or else show as it is.

Answer (score 1):

What error says?:

> It says that you have a column named newValue in dummy relation, which should be placed in group by section.

What is the important note?

> Each non-aggregate column in your SELECT statement's columns list,
>   which contains at least one aggregate function(refer to SELECT statement's columns), should be placed in
>   group by too.

So try this:

```
SELECT 
MAX(srNo)         AS srNo,
MAX(eventDesc)    AS eventDesc,
attributeType     AS attributeType,
MAX(companyCode)  AS companyCode,
empCode           AS empCode,
SUM(CAST(oldValue AS DECIMAL(10, 1))) AS oldValue,
CASE 
   WHEN isnumeric(newValue) = 1 THEN SUM(CAST(ISNULL(newValue,'0') AS DECIMAL(10, 1)))
   ELSE max(CAST(ISNULL(newValue,'0'))
END               AS newValue,       
MAX(creationDate),
createdByEmp,
reason 
FROM   
   dummy 
GROUP BY
creationDate, reason, createdByEmp, attributeType, empCode, newValue
```

Finally note that order of columns in Group BY is important, so you may need to place newValue column in the appropriate place inside Group By

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: @surajgole It seems that newValue is Varchar and you are using it inside Sum. Also newValue contains NULL value which is invali in SUM aggregate function. I am going to update my answer to cover this error too

Comment: @surajgole does it give the result now?

Comment: create table dummy(
srNo varchar(10),
eventDesc varchar(20),
attributeType varchar(20),
companyCode varchar(10),
empCode varchar(10),
oldValue varchar(20),
newValue varchar(20),
creationDate datetime,
createdByEmp varchar(10),
reason varchar(20)
);


insert into dummy values
(
'1','EmpSwipe Details','Swipe','G&B','369',null,'ESCD','2016-05-05 10:10:10','4511',null
);

Comment: insert into dummy values
(
'0','Leave Updation','CLSL','G&B','369','1','1','2016-06-05 10:10:10','4511','Excess CLSL'
);

insert into dummy values
(
'1','Leave Updation','CLSL','G&B','369','9.5','4.5','2016-06-05 10:10:10','4511','Excess CLSL'
);

Comment: for your reference.

Comment: @surajgole What you mean by max(CAST(newValue) ?

Comment: @surajgole it would be better to add a new question representing your new error. Thank you.